# Object gets fields from grandparent but not parent

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter-2

So I'm extending my custom Dashboard controller from my custom Admin_controller from my custom MY_controller from Codeigniter default CI_controller. Dashboard gets all the fields from MY_controller but none from Admin_controller.

Dashboard:

```
class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->data);
    }
}
```

Admin_Controller:

```
<?php

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['meta_title'] = 'Death Star CMS';
        $this->data['test'] = 'test';
        $this->load->model('user_m');
    }

}
```

MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = [];

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['errors'] = [];
        $this->data['site_name'] = config_item('site_name');
    }
}
```

CI_Controller:

```
    class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance =& $this;

        // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
        // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
        // so that CI can run as one big super object.
        foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
        {
            $this->$var =& load_class($class);
        }

        $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');

        $this->load->initialize();

        log_message('debug', "Controller Class Initialized");
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

var_dump($this->data) in Dashboard constructor shows only $data[] elements added in MY_controller ([errors] and [site_name]). How can I add elements to $data[] in Admin_Controller constructor?

It also fails to load user_m model.

Comment: Try adding `echo` statements in each constructor to see which are being executed.

Comment: I added echo get_class() . ' working </ br>' to all four controllers and as expected Admin_controller does not echo it's class name.

Comment: I tried creating a class hierarchy like yours, and all the constructors got run in the proper order. I can't see a reason why it's working differently for you.

Comment: It could have something to do with auto loader. I'm looking into that right now, but I don't think I'll find anything there, since it would not instantiate any class that extends Admin_Controller if the class was not auto loaded.